# How can I resolve this error with DOCTYPE? RESOLVED

Tags: html, google-chrome, doctype

Visual studio working incorrectly.

The only thing I did was use the "!" to already have the base code and I put  hiiiiiii  in the body and it gave an error with the DOCTYPE, everything is fine but Google says "One or more documents in this page is in Quirks Mode, which will render the affected document(s) with quirks incompatible with the current HTML and CSS specifications.

Quirks Mode exists mostly due to historical reasons. If this is not intentional, you can add or modify the DOCTYPE to be `<!DOCTYPE html>` to render the page in No Quirks Mode."

I tried uninstalling the application, downloading it from the Microsoft Store, opening the code through Microsoft Edge instead of Google, but I still get a white screen, nothing I put in appears, not even a simple

And I opened the correct index.html too, if anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hiiiii</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJkZl.png)
[google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYBiw.png)

Comment: The code in the image isn't the page you're viewing in Google (= Chrome browser). This is evident from the code in the "elements" tab from the developer tools. There can be many reasons for that, from just selecting the wrong file to cache issues.

Comment: If you provide more details about your HTML code, especially the structure around the DOCTYPE declaration, I might be able to offer more specific assistance.

Comment: left the code I put in the image with the description "code" and what appeared on Google with the image with the description "google" @Mahesh Prajapati

Comment: I opened it through windows explorer and the page has the same name, it's on the same page, I'm opening it correctly but the code doesn't seem to come, and I cleared the Google cache and nothing changed, other than that I already opened it using Microsoft Edge (and nothing), there are just a few more errors, being them "<html> element must have a lang attribute: The <html> element does not have a lang attribute, "Documents must have <title> element to aid in navigation", "A 'viewport' meta element was not specified." and "Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode". @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Thanks. I tested the code in several browsers and they all show the "hiiiii" text, without any issues.

Comment: Do you have any idea what I can do? delete visual studio, format the pc something like that? @KIKOSoftware

Comment: No, since I don't know what causes the problem I cannot suggest any course of action.

Comment: Solved, I found it strange to open F12 on Google and there was no code, so I told the gpt chat and he advised me to press Ctrl + S to save the code and it worked, now I'm going to watch the video to put this in automatically, thanks for the help. @KIKOSoftware